como cambiar la posicion del alt de una imagen que no se carga
cuando una imagen no se carga correctamente se visualiza el atributo "alt" con la descripcion de la imagen faltante.
Mi duda es como darle estilos para que se centre en el contenedor en lugar de estar en una esquina, se ve en la imagen el alt: "De noche con el diablo" ya que no cargo la imagen que va de fondo en el recuadro celeste
NOTA: lo de "AGO" es parte del diseño. 
Muchas gracias de ante mano.

Algo así? https://stackoverflow.com/q/1212104/

sin código este es un problema muy difícil de reproducir y tomará mucho tiempo

No me pareció necesario colocar el código para reproducirlo... alt es un atributo de cualquier imagen @RuslanLópez. No es complejo reproducir algo propio de html. Por eso coloque imagen sobre a qué me referia. Te agradezco si retiras el negativo

Gracias por tu respuesta @Mateo,  pero eso centra la imagen y yo estaba buscando centrar el ALT de la imagen cuando esta no aparezca. JorgeGuz dio con la solución

Puedes centrar ALT utilizando css para darle tanto a la imagen un tamaño como un espacio definido a través de la altura, anchura y utilizando sus propiedades flex a posteriori cambiar la posición del texto así como otras propiedades del elemento.
Dándole a alt estilos mediante css con "clase[alt]" puedes colocarlo en la posición que necesitas o darle os estilos que precises. Comparto un ejemplo de como podría utilizarse esta solución:


img.cambiaALT {
  width: 350px;
  height:250px;
  align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

img.cambiaALT[alt] {
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    line-height: 200px;
}
<div class="contieneIMG">
  <img class="cambiaALT" src="noimagen.jpg" alt="Este ALT ha sido modificado por CSS">
 </div>




Excelente! Muchas gracias por tu respuesta,  era justo lo que buscaba
